# How do you write and execute Ruby tests in a Ruby interpreter?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, interpreter

I was working with the [lotrepls](http://lotrepls.appspot.com/) Ruby interpreter, and I want like to write tests in the interpreter that I can then write Ruby code to pass. In Python, I can write doctests and then write code to pass the doctests. For example:

```
>>> b  
1
```

This tests that b=1, and entering b=1 will get this doctest to pass.

Is there a similar way to write tests in a Ruby interpreter, execute them, write code to pass the tests, and then execute the test again? Is there a Ruby doctest equivalent? For my application, I will execute tests and code in a hosted interpreter like lotrepls rather than install something on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's **[`RubyDocTest`](http://rubydoctest.rubyforge.org/)**, but I'd encourage you to look at something like **[RSpec](http://rspec.info/)** or another modern BDD/TDD framework.

It's pretty easy to write tests there too, and you get access to complex and/or custom assertions that you can't really get in a doctest. For instance, here's a simple set of tests for a baseball scoring app:

```
describe BaseballScorer do
  before :each do
    @s = Scorer.new(Game.new)
  end

  it "should score a 0-0 game when no runs are hit" do
    @s.home.score.should == @s.away.score.should == @s.total_runs
  end

  it "should record runs that are hit" do
    @s.game.run_hit(:away)
    @s.away.runs.should == @s.away.score.should == 1
  end

  # ...
```

Comment: Thanks John. Can I execute spec in an interactive session without reading in specs from a file? Can I enter in the code above in an IRB session and then run something like:

>> spec BaseballScorer #Rather than >> spec BaseballScorer.rb

Comment: Specs aren't associated with particular classes, per se. That is instead of `describe BaseballScorer`, I could have written `describe "Our baseball scoring algorithm"`. You can run the specs in a particular file with a SpecRunner; if you instantiate one of those, then you can run the tests. So the CLI interface is a little harder than a doctest would be. But you can run a Rake task to just run your specs, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks John. What is the simplest way to instantiate a SpecRunner instance and pass specs into it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old post but I faced the same problem some months ago.

John's answer is correct but if you want to use something similar to a irb session you could try [byexample](https://byexamples.github.io/byexample/), in particular it [supports Ruby](https://byexamples.github.io/byexample//languages/ruby)

For example you can write a Markdown doc like this:

````
This is an awesome expression:

```ruby
>> 1 + 2
=> 3

```
````

Then you just run from the shell

```
$ byexample -l ruby your-markdown-doc.md
[PASS] Pass: 1 Fail: 0 Skip: 0
```

You could also embed the test inside a Ruby comment like

```
# square 2
# => 4
def square x
  x * x
end
```

And that's it. The example is executed and checked so your doc works as regression test as well.

*Disclaimer*: Like I said, I had the same desire to do TDD in Ruby so I wrote [byexample](https://byexamples.github.io/byexample/). I really hope than others find it as much as useful and I do.